# Tesseract training data and model weights - how was the model trained and where are the weights stored?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Ever since version 4, Tesseract has been using a LSTM for text recognition. But what I have not been able to find out is the training data/training process used to train the LSTM. I have the following questions -

1. Is there any documentation of how the LSTM in tesseract was trained?
2. Where are the model weights of the trained model stored? I've looked at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract, but there doesn't seem to be a binary or any such usual file format that you'd be used to when using pytorch or tensorflow.

   a. On a separate note - what is the LSTM used for? Based on this presentation here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs/blob/main/das_tutorial2016/2ArchitectureAndDataStructures.pdf, it seems the LSTM is only used for line recognition, and not character recognition/classification? Is this true?

EDIT:

1. Regarding the training data - I found this comment https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/654#issuecomment-274574951 on the github repository, but am still unable to find where the model weights are stored. If someone can help me with that, it would be great!